# How to animate UIView inside UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionviewcell, uiviewanimation

I have created a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and it contains a subView named `animView` which I intend to animate. The shape of `animView` is a regular vertical rectangle.

In the `configureCell()` method, I use the code below to configure the cells and create an animation, but I do not see the animation.

```
animView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 0.5)
self.layoutIfNeeded()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
    self.animView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

However, when I try to animate whole cell, I see the cell animate successfully.

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 0.5)
self.layoutIfNeeded()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

I appreciate your time and answer.

**EDIT:**

As per the suggestions, I changed where I call the animation as shows below. Now, when I try to animate whole cell it is working. However, I want to animate the animView which is a subview of the custom UICollectionViewCell (BarCell). But it is not animating. Any ideas?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cells = collectionView.visibleCells
    for cell in cells {
        let current = cell as! BarCell
        let curAnimView = current.animView

        curAnimView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: current.animFillHeightCons.constant)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7) {
            curAnimView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start animation for only visible cells.
Here is how you can do that.

add this

> UIScrollViewDelegate

It will provide the method

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let cells = colAnim.visibleCells
            for cell in cells
            {
                let current = cell as! testCollectionViewCell
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
                    current.animView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -400, y: 0)
                //Change this animation
                })
            }
        }
```

Also make sure do this also.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "testCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! testCollectionViewCell
        cell.animView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)// This one
        return cell
    }
```

By doing this you can achieve animation only when cell is visible.
Thanks.

Comment: Why need to find visible cells? collectionView has delegate method for which cell will display to the screen: `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. Use the delegate to do your animation

Comment: Thank you, I implemented my animations in the method you recommended, works when I needed.

Comment: I noticed, only the first Cell is animating, even though I loop through visible cells. Any ideas?

Comment: I did edit the question. I am trying to animate within UITableViewCell, or I can access to animView from ViewController inside cellForItemAt. Your code works on whole Cell but not the subview of the cell (which is animView in this case).

Comment: AnimView is the view that you want animate in cell.

Comment: @DhruvKhatri exactly, so how to make it animate?

Comment: @sc13 as I did it will animate the inner view. Not cell view. Just try this and scroll your tableview.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 conditions to make it happen:

1. You will need to reset the properties you are animating every cell binding
2. You will have to start the animation only when the cell is about to be visible

Also, there are exceptions (like what I had), sometimes the cell binding or the layout of your collection is complex or custom thus, in these cases we will have to delay the animation so it will actually work.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 // your dequeue code...
 // ...

 // Reseting your properties as described in 1
 cell.myImageView.alpha = 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 let myCell = cell as! MyCell
 // As described in 2
 myCell.animate()
}


class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
 func animate() {
  // Optional: As described above, if your scene is custom/complex delaying the animation solves it though it depends on your code
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        // Animation code
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
                       delay: 0,
                       options: [.autoreverse, .repeat]) {
            self.seenNotSeenImageView.alpha = 0.5
        }
  }
 }
}
```

There's also a third condition:
If your cell will be covered by another VC, you will want to initiate the same `animated()` method as follow, in your viewWillAppear of the VC that holds the collectionView:

```
 collectionView.visibleCells.forEach{($0 as? MyCell)?.animate()}
```